# locating element with one class out of multiple classes inside a div using xpath in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have below two input fields and I have to find there location I can't use class selector cause iI have to identify element based on `formcontrolname` and `ng-invalid class`

```html
<div>
<input _ngcontent-thn-c28="" formcontrolname="nic_no" igxinput="" type="text" placeholder="00000-0000000-0" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid igx-input-group__input">
</div>

<div>
<input _ngcontent-thn-c28="" formcontrolname="username" igxinput="" type="text" placeholder="UserName" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid igx-input-group__input">
</div>
```

Therefore I'm using xpath. Below is what I did:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/input[(@formcontrolname='nic_no') and (@class='ng-invalid')]"); 


driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/input[(@formcontrolname='nic_no') and (@class='ng-invalid')]");
```

But I'm getting error apparently I have to write all classes name inside `@class`, like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/input[(@formcontrolname='nic_no') and (@class='ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid igx-input-group__input')]");
```

If I do like above then I won't get error but I need to use only one class name, cause there are changes more classes may include and reduce from this list of classes.

Answer (score 6):

**You should use contains:**

equals validates the attribute value is exactly equal to given value. As the attribute class value is "ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid igx-input-group__input" you cannot say @class="ng-invalid"

You should use contains instead

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/input[(@formcontrolname='nic_no') and contains(@class,'ng-invalid')]");
```

**Or use CSS:**

In css class can be mentioned as tag.classname:

```
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div>input.ng-invalid[formcontrolname='nic_no']")
```

If you **want to have exact class match :**

you can use [attribute='value'] syntax:

```
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div>input[class='ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid igx-input-group__input'][formcontrolname='nic_no']")
```

Comment: this worked  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div>input.ng-invalid[formcontrolname='nic_no']") but my question is for knowledge purpose why didn't contains work?  contains searches for the similar text it should have worked why didn't it?

Comment: @anmolagha it should work try using just contains and see if it works

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign